# Configure Jenkins and teamcity to run a job on every commit in SVN repository

Tags: svn, jenkins, teamcity

I am actually new to project and need your help.

I want to implement release branch strategy in my project.

Plan is, whenever the developers check-in changes through SVN,the commit should go to the code review tool ( in my case Teamcity) and from there it should start compilation in jenkins ( will run one build job).

Once the compilation is successful then will add reviewers to that commit.
Once review is done we need to merge that particular commit into SVN trunk.

So that we will not break the trunk because of faulty commits.

Can some one please explain how to achieve this.

If you give me the idea, I will explore and work on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TeamCity and Jenkins are both Continuous Integration tools, not code review tools. Therefore it's not really clear how you use them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [post-commit hook with TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+VCS+Post-Commit+Hooks+for+TeamCity#ConfiguringVCSPost-CommitHooksforTeamCity-Settinguppost-commithookonSubversionserver). The hook has to be applied to SVN repository.

To run Jenkins job from TeamCity, use Google Search. Here is a relevant post on StackOverflow: [Send command from TeamCity to run automation tests on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157797/send-command-from-teamcity-to-run-automation-tests-on-jenkins)